# Header format of imported excel files into Spotfire IronPython?

Tags: excel, ironpython, spotfire

I have a script that writes multiple excel files and I am trying to have another script in Spotfire that creates visualizations from these files. I am getting a "Failed to execute data source query for data source" error, which I believe is due to the header format.

I have tried having my first script export the data in all sorts of alignments, but for some reason it doesn't work unless I manually go into each one and click some random formatting stuff for the headers.

I guess I could have my second script open and do some random formatting before trying to import, but is there a way the files could go straight from the first to second script?

Comment: We can only guess at what your data looks like, or what your scripts are doing, so it's not clear how we could offer any suggestions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by creating sbdf files instead: https://support.tibco.com/s/article/How-to-export-python-data-frames-to-Spotfire-SBDF-files-from-external-python-engines

I get a list of all generated files in the folder and import data:

```
for file in filenames:
    page = Document.Pages.AddNew(os.path.basename(file))

    # data import
    name = os.path.basename(file)
    status, table = Document.Data.Tables.TryGetValue(name)
    ds = Document.Data.CreateFileDataSource(file)
    ds.IsPromptingAllowed=False

    if status:
        table.ReplaceData(ds)
    else:
        new = Document.Data.Tables.Add(name, ds)
```